SAS inserting observations from textfile, incomplete read
Having a textfile containing lines like
Mailtext = '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAkACQAAD/4QBaRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABQMBAAUAAAABAAAASgMDAAEAAAABAAAAAFEQAAEAAAABAQAAAFERAAQAAAABAAAOwlESAAQAAAABAAAOwgAAAAAAAYagAACxj//bAEMAAgEBAgEBAgICAgICAgIDBQMDAwMDBgQEAwUHBgcHBwYH';output;
if I read the line, then text is trunked, it appears text like
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAkACQAAD/4QBaRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABQMBAAUAAAABAAAASgMDAAEAAAABAAAAAFEQAAEAAAABAQAAAFERAAQAAAABAAAOwlES
AAQAAAABAAAOwgAAAAAAAYagAACxj//bAEMAAgEBAgEBAgICAgICAgIDBQMDAwMDBgQEAwUHBgcHBwYH
Mailtext = ' AND ';output; is ignored.
%let work_path=.. base64.txt;
/*
    content of base64.txt file 1 Line:
    Mailtext = '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAkACQAAD/4QBaRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABQMBAAUAAAABAAAASgMDAAEAAAABAAAAAFEQAAEAAAABAQAAAFERAAQAAAABAAAOwlESAAQAAAABAAAOwgAAAAAAAYagAACxj//bAEMAAgEBAgEBAgICAgICAgIDBQMDAwMDBgQEAwUHBgcHBwYH';output;
*/
%macro read;
    %let filrf  = myImage;
    %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf, &work_path.));
    %let fid=%sysfunc(fopen(&filrf));  

    %if &fid > 0 %then

     %do %while(%sysfunc(fread(&fid))=0);                                                                                                  
        %let rc=%sysfunc(fget(&fid, c));                                                                                                
        &c.                                                                                                                       
     %end; 

    %let rc=%sysfunc(fclose(&fid)); 
%mend read;
%macro mail;

    Data Mail;
        attrib  MAILTEXT LENGTH=$256;
        keep Mailtext;

             /* other macros inserting observations */    

            %read

        /* other macros inserting observations */ 
    ruN;


%mend;
%mail

no idea which options to be set in order to read and insert the hole line

Because %read resolve to &c and &c resolve to content of textfile: Mailtext = '...'; output;, so SAS actually run this assignment statement and output. You can use mprint option to check it.

When using fget function, you'd better add the third parameter to specify input length, or it would be 8 and may cause trunc.

What is the actual goal here?  Because you could just replace your call to the read macro with a %INCLUDE statement.  But if the file is an image file that will not be valid SAS code.

If the goal is to make a macro that emits the contents of a file then you could use the MODE=3 option of this macro:  https://github.com/sasutils/macros/blob/master/fread.sas

Based on your comment on the deleted answer "I´m building a complex html Mail with tables" this looks like an https://xyproblem.info/  Explain your actual problem.
